# I need some help cancelling a pending eth transaction from my coinbase wallet

Tags: pending-transactions

Long story short.

I wanted to partake in a free nft mint but messed up and lower the gas.

The transaction has been pending for 9 days and the gas is far too low to ever go through.

I have since tried to transfer eth out of my coinbase wallet into my coinbase account but now that transaction is pending since the one before it never went through.

I went to metamask and input the nonce # of the first pending transaction. I increased the gas but I keep getting an error saying

"Insufficient Funda for gas, price +value.

My account shows I have enough eth but I think that eth is part of the 2nd pending transaction.

I'm stuck.

Do I need to have more eth then try again ?

Any help would be amazing as I'm not trying to lose 1k.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you might be trying to set the gas price **too** high.

If you use the same nonce as the pending transaction and the default gas price offered by metamask it should replace it.

If the same error persist I'd try importing the seed to Metamask in a different browser.